# Ubuntu 20.04 running really slow

Tags: 20.04, nvidia

I have just freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an external SSD.

My problem is that whenever I try to install or run any software computer hangs for nearly a minute.
Even when performing simple actions, such as opening a new terminal or Firefox, it works really slow when it should not.

Some of my computer characteristics are

- HP Victus 16 Laptop, AMD Ryzen 7 5899h Radeon Graphics x16, 16GB RAM.
- Nvidia GeforceRTX 3050
- SSD 128GB
- Bios is version F.11

Some usefull outputs I am getting may be:
[`free -h`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr0NC.jpg)

[`top`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHwDv.jpg)

Thank you in advanced.

Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` is:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile] (rev a1)
DeviceName: NVIDIA Graphics Device
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 88ec
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
--
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c5)
DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 88ec
Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Have previously installed propietary driverNVIDIA 525

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command. AS TEXT PLEASE not as a screenshot!

Comment: Have added output above @Pilot6

Comment: Nvidia looks good. I have no more ideas.

Comment: Can you try to disable gnome-shell extensions?